# Using jQuery in HTML5 Workers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-worker

I want to perform some threaded work within a HTML5 worker. Workers currently work on a separate Javascript file or can be inlined in some way.

```
var worker = new Worker("some_work.js");
```

However, I would like to use jQuery within `some_work.js` as for example `$.get` without manually coping the source into `some_work.js`.

Has anyone an idea how to solve that?